# Android Gradle , All Modules Access Each other like being one module

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

suppose we have modules A , B , C , D , E , F , G and their packages are unique .

how could we share all packages and codes through all modules like there are all in a single project without the traditional dependecies way and without coping all packages into single project.

i want a way that keeps modules separated on disk and not just coping modules to each other. i know that including modules by coping them is a solution!

i want something in gradle like :

```
allprojects{

make all modules classes accessible to each other!

}
```

i don`t want to add all other modules as dependencies per each module!

Comment: Make a single library with all classes. I think that it is quite impossible to do it without adding dependencies and pay attention to circular dependencies!

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti 
i told you that i want gradle based solution and i am also aware of circular references , that is why i have asked this Question!